# Python Split Specific case handling

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split

Several numbers do not split up even after using split function

```
707 K   -7 -7 -6 -8 -2 -5 -8 -8  2 -5 -4 -7 -6  6 -8 -6 -7 -4  8 -6
708 L    0  0 -2 -3 -3  1  3 -3  0 -1 -3  4 -2 -5 -2  0  0 -3 -2  0
709 V   -7-10 -9-10 12 -9-10 -9 -9 -8 -8 -9 -8 -9 -9 -5 -7 -9 -4 -7
710 P   -1 -2  2  1 -2  1  2 -1  1 -4 -4  2 -3 -4  3  1  0 -1 -3 -4
711 E   -3 -3 -3  1 -6  1  5 -3  2  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -5 -2 -1 -4  0  0
712 C   -7-10 -9-10 12 -9-10 -9 -9 -8 -8 -9 -8 -9 -9 -4 -7 -9 -9 -7
713 S   -4 -4  1  1 -5 -2 -1  6 -1 -8 -7 -3 -7 -4 -2 -1 -3 -4 -4 -7
```

This matrix is from a text file and is very large ( both by number of lines in file as well as number of such files ) .

I successfully read the lines in python and split them up as

```
m = fp.readline(); [fp is the file pointer and reading is done in loop]

m = m.split() ; [splitting by elements ]

m = map(int,m[2:22]); [ mapping to make strings as integers from index 2 to 22 ]
```

but this gives an error for lines 709 and 712 ( see extreme left of matrix )

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#150>", line 1, in <module>
    map(int,m[2:22].split())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-7-10'
```

That's because '-7-10' didn't split up as expected '-7' '-10' due to formatting errors in files.

So question is how can I handle this formatting error so that I split and process the integers like other lines in a matrix ? Please remember this has to be done for very large lines and files so manually editing the formatting error is not feasible although such errors in a single file is within 100. Please help me ... thank you

Comment: Split the string by index positions instead of by space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform a `replace` on all negative signs to ensure that they're preceded by at least one space:

```
m = "-7-10 -9-10 12 -9-10 -9 -9 -8 -8 -9 -8 -9 -9 -5 -7 -9 -4 -7"
print m.replace("-", " -").split()
```

Result:

```
['-7', '-10', '-9', '-10', '12', '-9', '-10', '-9', '-9', '-8', '-8', '-9', '-8', '-9', '-9', '-5', '-7', '-9', '-4', '-7']
```

Of course, this only helps if it's a negative number that's butting up against its neighbor. If you have colliding values like:

```
707 K   -1 -2 -3
707 K   -4123 -6
```

Then you can't easily separate the -4 from the 123.

Comment: No i don't have positive mixed up numbers... and the problem was with negative numbers only and I resolved it.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could (as Simeon points out in the comments) just parse the numbers by fixed position; this comprehension does it by looping from 7 to 67, stepping by 3 and just converting the substring to an integer; (fields in your sample seem to start at posiiton 7 and each be 3 characters long)

```
>>> m
'709 V   -7-10 -9-10 12 -9-10 -9 -9 -8 -8 -9 -8 -9 -9 -5 -7 -9 -4 -7\n'

>>> a = [int(m[pos:pos+3]) for pos in range(7,67,3)]

>>> a
[-7, -10, -9, -10, 12, -9, -10, -9, -9, -8, -8, -9, -8, -9, -9, -5, -7, -9, -4, -7]
```

Comment: yes this also works... but its more similar to the simeon's answer... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re` module to find all substrings matching a specific regex pattern:

```
>>> x = "-7-10 -9-10 12 -9-10 -9 -9 -8 -8 -9 -8 -9 -9 -4 -7 -9 -9 -7"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall( r"-?[0-9]+", x )
['-7', '-10', '-9', '-10', '12', '-9', '-10', '-9', '-9', '-8', '-8', '-9', '-8', '-9', '-9', '-4', '-7', '-9', '-9', '-7']
```

Of course, if you might get `7, 123` formatted as `7123`, then your only option is to split the string by indices rather than content patterns.

Answer (score 0):

As the data you are dealing is a fixed format data, its ideal to use the [struct](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/struct.html) module and parse the data rather than using `split`

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> line="712 C   -7-10 -9-10 12 -9-10 -9 -9 -8 -8 -9 -8 -9 -9 -4 -7 -9 -9 -7"
>>> format_string = "<3s2s2s"+"3s"*20
>>> unpack(format_string,line)
('712', ' C', '  ', ' -7', '-10', ' -9', '-10', ' 12', ' -9', '-10', ' -9', ' -9', ' -8', ' -8', ' -9', ' -8', ' -9', ' -9', ' -4', ' -7', ' -9', ' -9', ' -7')
```